problem generating java artifacts from WSDL (from Italian ERP Mago4 by Microarea) using glassfish
I have been using for a few years the webservices exposed by the italian ERP Mago4 by Microarea, from my java programs.
I am trying to extend the use, but a WSDL seems to have problems.
In detail, calling:
wsimport http://localhost:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?wsdl          -XdisableAuthenticator   -generateJWS -XadditionalHeaders       -keep -Xnocompile -extension -d generated

returns a long list of errors, but basically are 2 kinds. Here an extract:

[WARNING] Ignoring operation "RunBatchInUnattendedMode": more than one part bound to body
  line 1 of http://virtual-1:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?wsdl

[WARNING] Ignoring operation "RunReportInUnattendedMode": more than one part bound to body
  line 1 of http://virtual-1:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?wsdl

[WARNING] Non unique body parts! In a port, as per BP 1.1 R2710 operations must have unique operation signature on the wire for successful dispatch. In port TbGesSoap, Operations "GetApplicationDate" and "ClearCache" have the same request body block . Method dispatching may fail, runtime will try to dispatch using SOAPAction
  line 1 of http://virtual-1:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?wsdl

[WARNING] Non unique body parts! In a port, as per BP 1.1 R2710 operations must have unique operation signature on the wire for successful dispatch. In port TbGesSoap, Operations "GetApplicationYear" and "ClearCache" have the same request body block . Method dispatching may fail, runtime will try to dispatch using SOAPAction
  line 1 of http://virtual-1:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?wsdl

[WARNING] Ignoring operation "RunReport": more than one part bound to body
  line 1 of http://virtual-1:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?wsdl


The methods mentioned in each warning do not get generated, and that's a serious problem because I need to invoke them.
Here below are, for example, the portions of WSDL regarding RunReport:
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://virtual-1:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?xsd=xsd53" namespace="urn:Microarea.Web.Services.RunReport"/>

<wsdl:message name="RunReportIn">
<wsdl:part xmlns:q170="urn:Microarea.Web.Services.RunReport" name="reportNamespace" element="q170:reportNamespace"/>
<wsdl:part xmlns:q171="urn:Microarea.Web.Services.RunReport" name="arguments" element="q171:arguments"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="RunReportIn_Headers">
<wsdl:part name="HeaderInfo" element="tns:HeaderInfo"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="RunReportOut">
<wsdl:part xmlns:q172="urn:Microarea.Web.Services.RunReport" name="return" element="q172:return"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:operation name="RunReport">
<soap:operation soapAction="#RunReport" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="RunReportIn">
<soap:header message="tns:RunReportIn_Headers" part="HeaderInfo" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="RunReportOut">
<soap:header message="tns:RunReportOut_Headers" part="HeaderInfo" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="TBSoapFaultFault">
<soap:fault name="TBSoapFaultFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>

and
<wsdl:operation name="RunReport">
<soap:operation soapAction="#RunReport" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="RunReportIn">
<soap:header message="tns:RunReportIn_Headers" part="HeaderInfo" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="RunReportOut">
<soap:header message="tns:RunReportOut_Headers" part="HeaderInfo" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="TBSoapFaultFault">
<soap:fault name="TBSoapFaultFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>

Are there any workarounds ?
Microarea local assistance is very reluctant to address the problem, replying something like "but in C sharp we do not have the issue"
thank you
I tried to use different options (-XdisableAuthenticator   -XadditionalHeaders etc) but it did not solve.

Those are warnings, not errors. Why are the warnings an issue?

Those methods in the warning do not get generated. I need to invoke them

Without having a [mre] it is likely difficult that someone can help. That includes translated messages that are not useful to search for similar messages. Read [mre] and [ask] then [edit] your question to improve it. Also try changing temporarily the locale of your computer to English so you can share the literal English warning messages.

thanks. I just re-posted the errors after switching the computer to English. I also re-posted portions of the WSDL

Does this answer your question? Generate webservice from WSDL with Document/literal format

non at all. I can not edit the WSDL, as it is comes with the ERP Mago of Microarea

Then this problem can not be solved here. It is something that you need to take with that company and so is off topic for [so].

With cxf it works

You could post what you did to solve the issue as a solution.

Solution for generating the Java Artifacts:
instead of Glassfish, use Apache CXF and CloseableHttpClient.
Some details:
Previously I changed from CXF to Glassfish because of the faster speed at runtime (which, during debug, can be quite time-wasting).
Anyhow, one of the Mago ERP WSDL is coded in a way that Glassfish can not fully handle, and many methods get igonerd.
So, I am reverting back to Apache CXF. Anyhow, searching for any other Framework, I came across the use of the Apache HttpClient (!). It is not at all a framework to manage WebService, but you can create the SOAP XML envelope by "hand", and send it to the WebService server via HttpClient.
I  wrote the code to use Apache HttpClient and I checked on the CXF log files how to write the XML Soap.
The use of Apache HTTPClient results in a 4 times faster execution compared to Glassfish.
Here the code to call the WebService:
// Create HttpClient
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

// Prepare the SOAP request
String soapRequest = buildSoapRequest(strUserName, strCompanyName, strPassword, strAskingProcess);

// Prepare the HTTP POST request
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(strWsdlLocationMicroareaLoginManager);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
//httpPost.setHeader("SOAPAction", ""); // Specifica l'azione SOAP se necessario


httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "*/*"); // Specifica l'azione SOAP se necessario
httpPost.setHeader("SOAPAction", "\"http://microarea.it/LoginManager/LoginCompact\""); // Specifica l'azione SOAP se necessario

System.out.println(httpPost.toString());


StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(soapRequest);
httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);


String responseString = null;

// Execute the request
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)) {
     responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println("Response: " + responseString);

    // Handle the response (puoi usare una libreria per il parsing XML se necessario)
}            
strAuthenticationToken = getAuthToken(responseString);

here the code to prepare the XML SOAP:
//  ID: 1
//  Address: http://virtual-1/mago4/LoginManager/LoginManager.asmx
//  Encoding: UTF-8
//  Http-Method: POST
//  Content-Type: text/xml
//  Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["http://microarea.it/LoginManager/LoginCompact"]}
//  Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><LoginCompact xmlns="http://microarea.it/LoginManager/"><userName>skynet</userName><companyName>yesterday-italchair srl</companyName><password>skynet1</password><askingProcess>com.met.mago.MagoWebService/cxf</askingProcess><overWriteLogin>false</overWriteLogin></LoginCompact></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
    
private static String buildSoapRequest(String userName, String companyName, String password, String askingProcess) {

    return  
      "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><LoginCompact xmlns=\"http://microarea.it/LoginManager/\">"
    + "<userName>skynet</userName><companyName>yesterday-italchair srl</companyName><password>skynet1</password>"
    + "<askingProcess>com.met.mago.MagoWebService/cxf</askingProcess><overWriteLogin>false</overWriteLogin></LoginCompact></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
}

here the code to parse the answer:
public static String getAuthToken (String strXml) throws Throwable {
    // Parse the XML
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(strXml));
    Document doc = builder.parse(is);

    // Create XPath
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

    // Define XPath expression to retrieve authenticationToken
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//authenticationToken/text()");

    // Evaluate XPath expression against parsed XML document
    String strAuthenticationToken = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);

    return strAuthenticationToken;
}

And here the code, when using CXF, that makes CXF to show the messages before sending to the server (very useful to see how to write them)
JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean proxyFactory_1  = new JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean();

proxyFactory_1.setServiceClass(com.italchair.opensource.microarea.cxf.TbGes.it.microarea.loginmanager.MicroareaLoginManager.class);
javax.xml.namespace.QName SERVICE_NAME_1 = new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://microarea.it/LoginManager/", "MicroareaLoginManager");
proxyFactory_1.setServiceName(SERVICE_NAME_1);
proxyFactory_1.setWsdlLocation(strWsdlLocationMicroareaLoginManager);
            

proxyFactory_1.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
proxyFactory_1.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

